# Terraform, how to call 100 times module with seperate values

Tags: automation, terraform, devops, infrastructure-as-code

I have a problem with terraform configuration which I really don't know how to resolve. I have written module for policy assigments, module as parameters taking object with 5 attributes. The question is if it is possible to split into folder structure tfvars file. I mean eg.
I have main folder subscriptions -> folder_subscription_name -> some number of files tfvars with configuration for each of the policy assigment

Example of each of the file
testmap = {
var1 = "test1" 
var2 = "test2" 
var3 = "test3" 
var4 = "test4" 
var5 = "test5"
}
In the module I would like to iterate over all of the maps combine into list of maps. Is it good approach? How to achive that or maybe I should use something other to do it like terragrunt ?
Please give me some tips what is the best way to achive that, basically the goal is that I don't want to have one insanely big tvars file with list of 100 maps but splitted into 100 configuration file for each of the assignment.

Comment: Hi! To be honest, I think all of us will have a hard time of understanding what you mean. Could you describe what you want to achieve in a more concise way?

Comment: The question is preety simple how to keep  input variables for each of resource in seperate file instead of keeping all of them in one very big file

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment on the original question:

> The question is preety simple how to keep input variables for each of
> resource in seperate file instead of keeping all of them in one very
> big file

I would say you aim at having different `.tfvars` files. For example, you could have a `dev.tfvars` and a `prod.tfvars` file.

To plan your deployment, you can pass those file with:

```
terraform plan --var-file=dev.tfvars -out planoutput
```

To apply those changes

```
terraform apply planoutput
```